# Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Во втором — более подходит определение "тройное смещение", а не "тройной эксцентриситет", так как под третьим центром понимается ось потока среды.

С этим событием связано появление термина "эксцентриситет" в поворотном затворе. Я
понимаю, что эксцентриситет — это отклонение от определенного одного центра.

Таким образом, более корректное определение таких затворов - это затворы с двойным, тройным, четверным смещением, но не эксцентриситетом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все кавычки расставлены верно.

Поясню: слова, разъясняющие термины, выражения (в значении..., в смысле... и т. п.) берутся в кавычки( примеры: 1 -2).
В последнем примере кавычки не нужны, т.к. присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость. Подробнее об том -Реальные собственные условные имена 
См.: [Грамма.ру. Употребление кавычек](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.4)

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки, на мой взгляд, расставлены правильно.

Comment: Более подробно сейчас не могу ответить. Убегаю...

Comment: Больше всего волнует - не нужны ли кавычки в последнем предложении?

Comment: Не нужны. Бегу...

Comment: Спасибо большое.